# NSIndexPath: retrieving data from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsindexpath

I'm using `CoreData` in my dictionary app and what I want to achieve is showing a list of words in columns in `tableview` and I have successfully implemented that. Also, I have managed to pass through the `indexPath` value to another swift file through segue.

Since both files fetch data from the same database, `indexPath` was good enough and I could show it in another view controller.

However, I want to implement the left and right swipe features to show other words in view Controller. And it was easy when there were no sections.

This is what I have in `UITableViewController.swift` for `segue`:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showWordDetail" {

        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! WordDetailViewController
        if let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! EduDicTableViewCell) {
            destination.receivedindexPath = indexPath
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code from `UIViewController.swift` that receives `indexPath`:

```
let object = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(receivedindexPath) as? WordItem

    wordLabel.text = object?.word
```

and this is the output of `IndexPath`:

```
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
```

Is there anyway that I can show other data, using modified `indexPath?`

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can increment and decrement the index path by getting the row portion, modify it and create a new indexPath, if the row value is less than the number of items in the fetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe do

```
destination.receivedindexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: 0)
```

or

```
destination.receivedindexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: 1)
```

assuming the destination tableview has one section